# Does ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL blocks the thread when we make dialog visible

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe, jdialog

I have below code sample :

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Window;

import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
 class MyDialogParent extends JDialog {

     MyDialogParent ()
    {
        super(null,ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

    //    super.setUndecorated(true);
        super.setVisible(false);


        // Disable Alt-F4 and any other close key sequences (MMSmk90468).
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}

 class MyDialogChild extends JDialog {

     MyDialogChild (Window parent)
        {
         super(parent,ModalityType.MODELESS);
         setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
            setAlwaysOnTop(true);


        }
    }


public class MyDialogs {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        MyDialogParent parent=new MyDialogParent();
        parent.setSize(400, 400);

        parent.setVisible(true);
        System.out.println("1");
        System.out.println("2");
        System.out.println("3");

        MyDialogChild child=new MyDialogChild(parent);
        child.setLocationRelativeTo(parent);
        child.setSize(300, 300);
        child.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        child.add(new JPanel());

        child.setVisible(true);


    }
    }
```

Now the execution hangs after

> parent.setVisible(true);

I know the concept of ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL in terms of blocking  input to some top-level windows.

I thought its only the child frame will not receive any inputs or focus. In code I see differently.

I want to know how it works. Is it like the thread stops the execution once the parent frame gets visible. Does it go to some wait state?

What is the logic for various ModalityType in relation with the thread?

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. Nothing in Swing blocks any thread - although all processing, changes to layout and `JComponent` structure, etc must happen on the Swing thread.

Normally creating an entirely new window is safe on that front but still it would be worth creating your child on the swing EDT (using `invokeLater`).

Comment: Could you please explain this more elaborately. Please forgive me, I am not so expert in swings. And also it would be great if you can share your views that why the sysout statements are not executing after making parent visibility true

Comment: Also how can you say that it is not blocking any thread, I cannot see the execution going further in eclipse console just after making the parent visibility true???

Comment: Normally creating an entirely new window is safe on that front but still it would be worth creating your child on the swing EDT (using invokeLater). ...what you mean by this?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through in a debugger and seeing what happens? Are you sure no exceptions are being thrown?

Comment: yes, I am sure no exceptions are being thrown, you can also run the program that I have shared and confirm this

Comment: Also regarding debugging, I can see that debugger stops before sysout untill I close the parent frame

Comment: I don't have time to run your program for you. All I can suggest is you read up on the swing concurrency tutorials and on this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html and see if it helps you.

Comment: sure, I ll do that, thanks for the knowledge sharing